# Jenkins detecting more than one instance

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I realize that this question has been asked before but I feel like my case is different.

About five hours after I launch jenkins I sometimes see this message appear when loading the jenkins administrator panel:

> Jenkins detected that you appear to be running more than one instance of Jenkins that share the same home directory '’. This greatly confuses Jenkins and you will likely experience strange behaviors, so please correct the situation."

This is strange, it happens every time I launch it, eventually making Jenkins unusable. I installed Jenkins via homebrew and launch is via the jenkins CLI. I manually do this so I don't see how it's possible that Jenkins launches twice.

I reinstalled Jenkins after completely removing it. Still no luck.

Anyone have any issues like this before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - Jenkins detected running multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480876/error-jenkins-detected-running-multiple-instances)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem and solved it with following checks:

- Check if another java process is running which runs jenkins e.g. in unix using `top`
- If you're using tomcat, search for a second instance of tomcat having the jenkins.war exploded somewhere
- Could be helpful to just have one version of java installed